# "Mathematically mature" book on numerical analysis of PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, book-recommendation, numerical-calculus

I'm looking for a mathematically mature textbook on numerical analysis of PDE with a focus toward theory. Every book I look at seems to state in the preface that the book makes mathematical concession for readability for engineers, physicists, and the like. I'm looking for nice, general results (with rigorous proof) about convergence of finite difference schemes and on similar issues. Ideally, the book also shouldn't focus on the special case of two independent variables and should include a treatment nonlinear PDE (though perhaps there isn't much general theory for the nonlinear cases, so this isn't necessary).

Comment: Try LeVeque "Finite Difference Methods for Ordinary and Partial Differential Equations: Steady State and Time Dependent Problems" Quite a mouthful of a title.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I heard good things then one of the amazon comments read "It is a book for an applied mathematician (i.e. no rigorous proofs of convergence and nonsense like that)." which is basically the opposite of what I want.

Comment: I assumed that wouldn't be the case since it is the textbook for a grad level numerical analysis class at UC Berkeley. Your best bet would be to look for courses at universities and see what textbooks they use.

Comment: I am curious about why you would need such a book.. Typically “pure” mathematicians do not care much about numerical methods even if those are way more important than a good part of abstract mathematical nonsense. I would definitely choose a book written by an applied person.

Comment: I remember Teman's [_Numerical Analysis_](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789027703088), which struck me as possibly being what you want.

Comment: Strikewerda: Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations: https://www.amazon.com/Difference-Schemes-Partial-Differential-Equations/dp/089871639X/

Comment: Finite Element Analysis, Ivo Babuska: https://www.amazon.com/Finite-Element-Analysis-Barna-Szabó/dp/0471502731

Comment: Partial Differential Equations with Numerical Methods by Larsson - Thomee was the book we used in my Numerical PDEs course at Stanford

Comment: [Theoretical Numerical Analysis](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441904577) by Atkinson and Han is great for a really strong grounding of numerical methods for PDEs in functional analysis

Comment: @GReyes Because I want to have numerical methods which provably work. What's the point of an algorithm if we can't prove that it gives us what we want, i.e. solves the problem we set out.

Comment: I'll have to look through all these suggestions more tomorrow.

Comment: I think it is important to specify which kind of PDE are u interested in (elliptic, parabolic, hyperbolic) and a method which are you interested in (finite differencies, finite element method (FEM), collocation method, finite volumes). If you go for basic elliptic problems, then I would look to books about FEM. Some convergence results for this case are 
here: Mixed Finite Element Methods and Applications
Authors: Boffi, Daniele, Brezzi, Franco, Fortin, Michel https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642365188

Comment: @Keefer Rowan I get your point. In reality, however, there is a lot of empirical or semi empirical methods that people use without a proper justification as understood by mathematicians. Many of them work despite not having a clean proof. To give you an example many of the tricks used to train neural networks are purely empirical and they work. Proofs are seldom available and they work in ideal conditions which are far from the messy reality. A different example of the relative value of proofs: Calculus was created and was in good shape for 200 years before real numbers were defined properly.